# Why is 3 printed in this for loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Why does "3" get printed out in this code block's output:

Input:

```
n = range(4)

for num in n:
    print(num - 1)
else:
    print(num)
```

Output:

```
-1 
0
1
2
3
```

From my understanding, "3" should not be printed since:

1. num will never equal "4" since n are the literals 0 through 3 (not inclusive of 4),
2. when num equals its highest literal, which is "3", it will print "2".

I've read the question about the else statement in for and while loops in Python, but I do not see an iteration where "4" is called in the for loop hence triggering the any usage of the else statement since num stops at 3.

Thank you.

Comment: The `else` is executed because no `break` was encountered in the loop.

Comment: @khelwood Aw I see it now.  Thank you!

Comment: From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops): *"Loop statements may have an `else` clause; it is executed when the loop terminates through exhaustion of the iterable (with `for`) or when the condition becomes false (with `while`), __but not when the loop is terminated by a `break` statement__."*

Answer (score 2):

This gives us a sequence:

```
n = range(4)
```

```
0
1
2
3
```

This prints out the first four numbers:

```
for num in n:
    print(num - 1)
```

```
-1
0
1
2
```

And finally this prints out the final value of `num`:

```
else:
    print(num)
```

```
4
```

Comment: Yes, I realized that after the first comment but I appreciate this comment as it's very clearly written out.  Initially, I believed the life span of num ended when for loop ended; therefore, it would num would not proceed to the else statement.